# How to make Case Status read-only in Communities?

Tags: community, case, lightning-experience, read-only, status

We have implemented Communities portal to handle customer issues however we don't want users to edit the Case Status (should only be able to create and close cases -similar to SF Partner Support). We have tried the following ways with no luck:

- FLS through Customer Communities profile (field is greyed out)
- FLS through a custom Customer Communities profile (field is greyed out)
- FLS through a custom Permission Set (field is greyed out)
- Case page layout (field cannot be removed nor made read-only)

This environment has Lightning enabled.

I am no expert in Service Cloud but I know this behaviour doesn't align with standard case management workflows. So I am suspicious we might have misconfigured something.

I have read the following similar post but the only suggestion there is custom development (and I am curious whether it can be done without custom coding):

[How to make Lead Status field read-only in a profile?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/how-to-make-lead-status-field-read-only-in-a-profile)

Comment: Are you using Lightning Napili Community template? If yes, you can update the page layout and remove the Status field. Let me know if you need help!

Comment: @javanoob yes we are. How do we do it? Is it through page variations in the Community Builder?

Comment: Do you see something like this? http://imgur.com/a/W2RCO

Comment: @javanoob yes I do. I have tried dragging and dropping it inside the "Case Detail" page but I am not able to remove the Status field.

Comment: I am not able to find exactly how we did this and I am still looking into it. I will post here once I check with my colleague who configured this. Sorry for that.

Comment: @javanoob Did you ever discover how you accomplished this? We're running into this same struggle now. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MikeMiller I thought it was possible but it is not. Sorry for my misleading comments. My bad!